Is 愛しくなる a typo for 愛したくなる here?
In the below panel, 清香 and くるみ were sleeping together. To make sense of their conversation, I ought to mention that 清香 has a symptom where she forgets everything that happened in a day every time she sleeps. On the other hand, くるみ no longer has this symptom.
I am puzzled by the use of 愛しくなる. I think she is saying that "everyday, you (清香) become cuter little by little." It sounds bit odd, so I can't help but to suspect that it might be a typo for 愛したくなる. Maybe I am overthinking.

(Source: she is beautiful ch. 50)

Do you know the word いとしい?

@Angelos Yes I am aware

This is not a typo. This is the ku-form of 愛しい【いとしい】 followed by なる. And the subject of いとしくなる is undoubtedly 私.
However, 私は愛しくなる does not mean "I become lovely" in this context. Just like 怖い, 楽しい and many other adjectives, 愛しい means "causing affection" when it refers to a lovely thing or person, but it means "feeling affection" when it refers to the speaker themselves. 私は毎日毎日少しずつ愛しくなるよ means "Every day, I feel more and more affection for you" or "I grow attached to you day by day". On the other hand, あなたは毎日愛しくなる would typically mean "You're becoming more and more lovely every day".
